# Crystal Report Duplicate row

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Currently I am working on reports for my project. I designed one report in Crystal Reports and the connection is from database not from dataset, so I put this code which is in the print button:

```
Dim index As Integer = Me.dgrdItems.CurrentRow.Index
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(local)\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SAb;Integrated Security=True"
Dim selectConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
selectConnection.Open()

'Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(Conversions.ToString(Operators.ConcatenateObject(Operators.ConcatenateObject("SELECT * FROM Sales Where SalesNo='", Me.dgrdItems.Item(0, index).Value), "'")), selectConnection)
Dim dataSet As New DataSet
'adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Sales")
'Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(Conversions.ToString(Operators.ConcatenateObject(Operators.ConcatenateObject("SELECT * FROM SalesItem where ItemSalesNo= '", Me.dgrdItems.Item(0, index).Value), "'")), selectConnection)
''MsgBox(Me.dgrdItems.Item(0, index).Value)
''da.Fill(dataSet, "SalesItem")
''MsgBox(Me.dgrdItems.Item(0, index).Value)
''Dim da2 As New SqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * FROM StoreInfo where StoreName= '" & lblCompanyName.Text & "'"), selectConnection)
''da2.Fill(dataSet, "StoreInfo")

Dim selected As New rptSalesInvoiceSelected
selected.SetDataSource(dataSet)
Dim frmReportsViewer As New reportviewer
frmReportsViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = selected
'  AllObjects.frmReportsViewer.MdiParent = MainFormR
frmReportsViewer.Show()
frmReportsViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.PrintReport()
selectConnection.Close()
```

I made the above code comment and the data is loading from the database and shows duplicate rows in report. I don't know why this code in the print button is not working.

Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the current code never fills in the dataSet variable, I have to assume the commented code would normally run. If so, then that means you have 3 tables you are loading into your report. That also means you are doing "LINKS" in your database expert of CR. This means, if there are more than one record in any of those tables, you will have duplicates of the other records. This is standard database join behavior. If you don't have links between all 3 tables, that can cause the same type of issue. **Look at your links.**

Comment: as you see the filling report from dataset is commented, but when you call report, still showing data, I don't from where it retrieve data.